# Trigger updating a table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger here that supports inserting an 'invoice' into my database, but I want it to
automatically update the 'customer' in the 'customer' table by adding this new invoice to the customer's balance which is CUS_BALANCE
Here is my trigger so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `invoice` BEFORE INSERT ON `invoice` 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO invoice VALUES (customer, invoice, line, product, 
vendor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide an update statement inside the trigger or call a stored proc with parameters to update the customers balance from the trigger.

```
delimiter //
create trigger invoice_trigger before insert on invoice
for each row 
begin 
Update customers set balance = new.balance where id = new.id
end //
delimiter ;
```